# Hibernate default timestamp is fetched from DB or VM?

Tags: java, hibernate

In [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html), the explanation for timestamp is given as :

> When using timestamp versioning you can tell Hibernate where to
>   retrieve the timestamp value from - database or JVM - by optionally
>   adding the @org.hibernate.annotations.Source annotation to the
>   property. Possible values for the value attribute of the annotation
>   are org.hibernate.annotations.SourceType.VM and
>   org.hibernate.annotations.SourceType.DB. **The default is SourceType.DB**
>   which is also used in case there is no @Source annotation at all.

and also it says that:

**source (optional - defaults to vm)**

So after going through these 2 statements in bold, I am confused on exactly which one is default setting for Timestamp, whether it is VM or DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Javadocs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Source.html) for `org.hibernate.annotations.Source` mention that the default is VM:

> Default:
>
> > org.hibernate.annotations.SourceType.VM